# Phonegap background service - Android, iOS and Windows Phone

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to make a background service in Phonegap. 
*That checks for example every 10min to see if there is any new message.*
While there are native solutions I could find. 
I could not find an universal solution for this.

My Question: **What is the best way to make an universal background service for Phonegap.**

I want to support at least: **Android, iOS and Windows Phone.**

Comment: You should consider a push notification service as likely the best consistent behavior across platforms. Some platforms, with the exception of specific app types, cannot run as frequently as you mention to prevent battery drain.

Comment: And as written, this question is much too broad for StackOverflow. You'll want to find the most appropriate for each platform as a common solution will lead to a solution that may be no better than the platform that least matches your needs.

Comment: The check every 10 min was an example. While i can always search for the best solution for each platform independent. I want to make my code as universal as possible. This means when a new OS comes out the only thing that needs updating is Phonegap/Cordova and not a rewrite of function.

Comment: I'd still suggest sending push notifications rather than polling -- it's most likely to be "reasonably" consistent across platforms.